# treat json objects value as integer

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file which I am accessing through JS

```
latitude =data8.weblandmarks8[j].latitude + latitude;
```

should add all the latitudes so that I could average them later
instead  it just concatenates them
How should i achieve what I want to

Json entry

```
"latitude": "28.14331",
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Aside from using `parseFloat` you could convert to `Number`, it's slightly faster and usable for both integers and floats<sup>**1**</sup>:

```
latitude = Number(data8.weblandmarks8[j].latitude) + latitude;
```

<sup>**1**</sup> another advantage for integers is that you don't need to supply a radix.  `Number('09')` returns 9, whereas `parseInt('09')` (i.e. `parseInt` without a radix) returns 0 (that's because `parseInt` defaults to an octal - radix 8).

Answer (score 4):

Convert it to a number: You'll use the `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()` methods.

```
parseFloat('28.14331') // 28.14331
parseInt('28.14331', 10) // 28
```

Comment: use `radix` always of base 10 if you use `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the parseFloat function to turn the string into a number

```
latitude = parseFloat(data8.weblandmarks8[j].latitude) + latitude;
```